# How to group by on other model column with relationship rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Each ticket has 2 timeslots.

ticket.rb:

```
has_many :timeslots, through: :visits
```

visit.rb:

```
has_many :tickets
belongs_to :timeslot
```

timeslot.rb:

```
has_many :visits
belongs_to :ticket
```

What I need to get is the timeslots of each ticket in the group of 2. So

```
Ticket A - timeslot 1
Ticket A - timeslot 2
Ticket B - timeslot 1
Ticket B - timeslot 2
```

Query I am trying is:

```
Ticket.where(:zone_id => 1).includes(:user).joins(timeslots:
 :visits).group_by("visits.ticket_id")
```

But it says:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` is a ruby method expecting a block (doc: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

The SQL `GROUP BY` is provided by the `group` method of ActiveRecord (doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

In your case, this should work:

```
Ticket.where(:zone_id => 1)
      .includes(:user)
      .joins(timeslots: :visits)
      .group("visits.ticket_id")
```

Comment: It says: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "tickets.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
`

Comment: The thing is, you have multiple Ticket records for a single `ticket_id`, and in PostgreSQL it complains that it can't decide which Ticket record he should select. This is why you must use an `aggregate function` to tell postgreSQL which Ticket to select (ex: `max(tickets.id)`), but this won't solve your problem. Can you explain exactly what you want and expect? Not only on the db level but on the end-user level too (front-end or API side)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir Yoshiji. I am finally done with the solution of problem. :-)